# Premiere Pro issue with preview?

Tags: premiere, adobe

I'm not a pro when it comes to Premiere Pro and just wanted to cut a training video for my job (without bigger animations or something like this).

The finished video is displayed correctly in the preview. But as soon as I export it, or create a new partial sequence from the whole video, the following happens:

The individual clips move in their cutting, or in other words — at some points a few frames are removed at the front, and at the back a few additional frames are shown (the length etc. remains the same). This of course shifts the whole sound and I can see frames in the video that should not be visible.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more info: what frame rate and format are the files you're bringing in?  add a screen shot of the sequence settings, and tell us what frame rate and format the files are that you're exporting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Premiere Pro, so I don't provide the step-by-step instruction, but I know the basis of your problem.

In your original (compressed) video they are so-called **intra-frames** (aka **keyframes**), which contains the full info about the particular frame, and other frames (inter-frames) which contain — simply said — only differences from the previous intra-frames.

[image]

In other words:

- every **intra-frame** is *independent of others frames*, while
- **non-intra-frames** are *dependent* on *the nearest previous intra-frame*
  (and — maybe — from other frames, too).

Let suppose there is **1** intra-frame every **10 seconds** (i.e. at time stamps 0 s, 10 s, 20 s, etc.),
and the “other” frames are between them.

Now, you want to cut the 20 s video from the time 13 s (i.e. the range **13 s – 33 s**).

The frame at the position 13 s is **not** an intra-frame — it needs the previous intra-frame (at position 10 s) to obtain the full picture.

So your software simply **adds** the 3 s part from 10 s in front of your request, and **cuts-off** the last 3 seconds. The result will be a clip in the range **10 s — 30 s**.

But the situation is not so desperate. You have to force Adobe Premiere Pro to re-encode the 13 – 33 s part of original video, i.e. to first compute the frame at position 13 s, then mark it as intra-frame, and make subsequent frames dependent of this new intra-frame.

How?

As I told, I don't know the exact answer. But you have to **avoid** enabling properties as “Direct Copy”, “Fast Copy”, “Without Re-encoding”, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Change your export setting
and use the "frame sampling" option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I used it already and it isn't working...